# Generic inquiry on joined tables destroy navigation

Tags: acumatica

I have an working generic inquiry and wanted to expand it by a field in a related table
[image]

The table ContainerHistory is connected to the SerialContainer by the ContainerID. And there is no reference from SerialContainer to ContainerHistory

This is the definition for the result grid and the navigation
[image]

[image]

On first glance everything seems to work correctly, but after a bit of testing I realized that the navigation to the edit-screen always takes me to the entry on top of the inquiry. Has anyone experienced something similar or can give me a hint on how to deal with this navigation error?

Comment: Do you have any attributes like PXPrimaryGraph on these DACs? The PXPrimaryGraph affects the navigation of the GI

Comment: Useful tip, but this is not the case for both DACs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Grouping on your GI?
I have seen this happen when the primary Grouping Field(s) do not match the Key fields for the Inline Navigation..

eg if your keys for navigation are LotSerialNbr and InventoryID - make sure your GI is also grouped by those keys.

Introducing another table can sometimes result in duplicate records which confuses the Inline navigation (at least in my experience)

Comment: I tried grouping with LotSerialNbr and InventoryID, but it didn't solve the navigation error